# react native router flux: override android hardware back key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Currently, when I press the android hardware back key, the react router flux will call the Actions.pop() method. Is there anyway to prevent it call the method to prevent in go back previous scene because I want to jump to other scene. From example scene A to scene B, scene B to scene C, when press back key in scene C, I want to go to scene A. I tried

```
componentWillMount() {
    // Disable back button by just returning true instead of Action.pop()
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      return true;
    });
  };
```

Comment: Try to delete the Scene B from "route" while pressing back button from Scene C.

Answer (score 0):

According to [BackAndroid docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.39/docs/backandroid.html#backandroid):

> Detect hardware back button presses, and programmatically invoke the default back button functionality to exit the app if there are no listeners or if none of the listeners return true. The event subscriptions are called in reverse order (i.e. last registered subscription first), and if one subscription returns true then subscriptions registered earlier will not be called.

So in a specific scene you can add a BackAndroid listener, do what ever you want in this listener and return true;

Another thing worth mentioning, is that you add the event listener in componentWillMount.
If the router is a descendant child of this component, this means that you register for the back event before the router is mounted so the router listener will be registered after your listener, and so will be called before your listener.
Try registering to the event in ComponentDidMount instead. This method is called after the router was mounted and its listener registered.